# When to use form vs model validation?

Tags: django, django-forms

Just curious. What is the best practice for when to use form vs model validation?
From what I understand currently, form validation should be used for:

- AJAX / HTTP requests params
- Forms that do not correlate to a model?

Another question is: I have a HTML form that roughly correlates to a model instance, do I use a ModelForm for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use `ModelForm`, if your form resembles model object even in a tiny bit.

If there are some minor differences (e.g. you don't use some of the fields or you want to use different error messages etc.) it's much easier to customize `ModelForm` then to use `Form` and implement all this functionality from scratch.

For more reference regarding `ModelForm` please checkout PyDanny's [Core Concepts of Django ModelForms](http://pydanny.com/core-concepts-django-modelforms.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am also trying to understand what is the difference/relation between form and model validation and I would like to share my notes that are formed after reading several docs.

I am currently interested in [Creating Forms from Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms)

@mariodev shared the document [Core Concepts of Django ModelForms](http://pydanny.com/core-concepts-django-modelforms.html) and this provided a good start.

> ModelForms select validators based off of Model field definitions

The main story behind the scenes seems to be the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principal. [This article](http://pydanny.com/overloading-form-fields.html) explains very well what exactly is the case here.

All right, all this is fair. The question is "Where in the Django Documentation is this explained"?

I bumped on a very [brilliant article](http://owtrsnc.blogspot.gr/2013/07/django-form-and-field-validation-process.html) where it states that:

> The form.full_clean() method is called by django at the start of the validation process (by form.is_valid(), **usually immediately after the view receives the posted data**).

Correct me if I am wrong but that line reads that everytime I enter data and hit 'enter' the validation process begins!

OK, this is simple now:

- The [validation on a ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) begins when we hit 'enter'.
- Django first [validates the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) by checking one by one every applicable validation method on [Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/), [Field Subclasses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass) (This is the documentation for a model's field subclass, not for a form field subclass), [Form Subclasses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#subclassing-forms) and [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) (since it is a ModelForm).
- Finally, it validates the [Model Instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

This is how all this works theoretically. The only thing that remains is to implement it.